# How to specify a different domain when using sencha app watch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Is there something like?

```
sencha app watch --host=mydomain.app
```

As we all know, the default domain is localhost:1841. I can define a custom port, but not a custom domain.

I haven't found anything related in the Sencha documentation. Any workaround? I need to serve on a custom domain to avoid cross domain CORS issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation of Sencha Cmd](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.0.0/guides/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html#advanced_cmd-_-cmd_reference_-_sencha_app_watch) you can:

1. Change the default address in `sencha.cfg` by setting `inspector.address` property.
2. Use the `config` command of `Sencha Cmd` to set a server and port:

```
sencha config --prop inspector.address=http://server:port/ \
    then \
    app watch --inspector
```